# How to kill Thread in my C# application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to kill/destroy the thread in my application on Button Click event.

```
        private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep();
        }
```

Does this event hang up my application?

That's the code where from my thread starts

```
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();`enter code here`
        myTable = msgDataSet.Tables["text"];
        DataRow[] myRow;
        myRow = myTable.Select();

        for (int x = 0; x < myRow.Count(); x++ )
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait(myRow[x]["msg"].ToString());
            SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
            int sleep = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            Thread.Sleep(sleep);
        }
        Thread Spam1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Send1));
        Spam1.Start();
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep puts active current(the one you run stop_btn_Click) thread to sleep, so it's normal that application hangs.

Comment: Which thread do you want to kill? Main thread of your app?

Comment: @lvar so Please tell how i can stop thread with hanging up my application?

Comment: @invisible Yes i want to close main thread of my application.

Comment: To close the main thread of the app (and everything else btw) without saving/cleaning up anything etc. this `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this article for why you should never try to call `Thread.Abort`:

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

The problem is that you break your exception safety within that thread.  This is because `Thread.Abort` will throw an exception within that thread at some arbitrary point, which might be right after a resource is loaded, but before the thread enters a try/catch that would support clean unloading of that resource.

Instead you should build co-operative cancellation into the code you run in that thread.  Then set some sort of "cancellation requested" state, and let the thread kill itself.  E.g.:

```
foreach(var value in aBunchOfData)
{
    if(isCancelled)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Continue processing here...
}
```

In this case you'd expose `isCancelled`, and have your parent thread set it to `true`.

This pattern is made clear if you [use a `BackgroundWorker` to implement your background thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: but how i can access my thread name to my button event? When i access my thread for aborting or suspending this give me following error Error : The name 'Spam1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @RizwanKhan: Look into BackgroundWorker.  Create an instance of it in your main form, and keep the background worker around as a member variable in the form.  BackgroundWorker gives you shared cancellation state that you can access from both threads.  See the link at the bottom, or google backgroundworker.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote will put UI thread to sleep->your application will hang. How do you implement threading? If you are using BackgroundWorker- you can [enable thread cancellation](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx), if you are using Task- you can provide [cancel token to it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx). If you are using Thread- you can choose [Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) method.
PS..If you want to stop your application(main thread)-you can:
 close main window || call application exit || call process kill....

Comment: Morgan-Graham but how i can access my thread name to my button event? When i access my thread for aborting or suspending this give me following error Error : The name 'Spam1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Rizwan Khan , 1st question: why do you even want to abort thread in the code above?..If you really DO- better use Task(in c#4) or BackgroundWorker(>=c#2). They are easier to control with presence of UI thread. Take a look at their samples. Btw, read http://www.albahari.com/threading/ . Better you understand the question yourself then use our answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forcefully shut down a thread, you can call [Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx) which will raise a ThreadAbortedException on the target thread

```
myThread.Abort()
```

The target thread has a chance to catch it and clean up any resources if needed (of course, it can also ignore it if it wants to by just catching the exception and moving on, but that is IMO bad practice)

Comment: @lsak-savo but how i can access my thread name to my button event? When i access my thread for aborting or suspending this give me following error Error : The name 'Spam1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You need to hold a reference to it. You get the ref when you do myThread = new Thread(...);