# Threading troubles - when should I and when should I not thread, for best performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My question is, when should I and when should I not thread?

Can anyone give some general rules?

Say I have an mainForm, and I want to do some business in another thread.

Should I:

- Create a new thread, like `Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));`
- Declare an delegate, like `myDelegate.BeginInvoke(IsyncCallback)` (delegate, not control, yes :)
- Create a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker()`

for the best performance?

Example scenarios:

- Fetch data from database to control, or serious background calculation
- Maybe multi threads if it's something like an ATM
- A thread you want to stay alive forever

And please, give me deep explanations, not like 'I guess' :)

What business is the new thread doing, you may ask? That's why I want some general rules, it might differ.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific?  You certainly have cast a wide net.

Comment: Why does just about every sentence end with an exclamation mark?

Comment: Well if someone have the skill, they could give me an general answer !

Comment: You can Google for general answers you know....

Comment: Well google did not give me the answer, and this is something i have beem thinkig of for a long time, please be nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For the best performance !

You should pick from these options not because of performance, but because of the facilities they provide.

Out of those options, `BackgroundWorker` has the best facilities.

- It directly supports cooperative thread cancellation ([the only correct type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8006040/232593))
- It supports an interface for pushing updates to your UI
- It supports automatic thread pooling.
  This can increase performance due to the system not having to spawn new threads to satisfy your request, but instead allocating from an existing pool of threads.

The other two options don't have quite as nice facilities built in.  In a nicely implemented UI application, you'd have to build them yourself, and I don't think most people would do much better perf-wise than the implementations for `BackgroundWorker` without a lot of work.

You might also want to consider [the Task Parallel Library in .Net 4.0 and above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).  It supports cancellation, more direct integration into the language, chained and dependent tasks, and other interesting features.

> [From comments:] Im not concerned - I just want to know the difference

[Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) is the original construct out of all these.  It provides basic threading support in .Net.  It is low level and should be avoided unless you don't have a better option that fits your needs.

[Delegate.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx) is a hook for allowing someone to create a task-based threading library.  Someone can pass that library a delegate, or that library could store a list of delegates.  From these it would call `BeginInvoke` on them to spawn threads.  These threads are allocated from a thread pool.  This is a building block, though at a higher level than `Thread`.  There are higher level facilities you probably want to use.

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is the most user friendly out of these options.  It is most useful for UI (GUI or command line) applications where you want to provide the user feedback about the status of a specific background task.  It also supports cooperative cancellation.  Both of these things are extremely common.

There are other facilities you didn't mention, like [using thread pools directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx), or the task parallel library.  Those are suited to yet other tasks, and are worth a look and consideration.

> And please, give me deep explanations, not like 'I guess' :)

People cannot guess perf for code they cannot run.  As a general rule for thread perf, you probably shouldn't be concerned about it unless you're writing an extremely processor intensive algorithm.  And then you should usually be concerned with your algorithm and making it [fully parallelizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) *before* worrying about low level details like perf of the thread facility.

You should definitely profile your code to determine the bottlenecks in your codebase and see if you can improve them.  You can't preempt profiling with a set of programming rules.

> Fetch data from database to control - or serius background calculation !

DB fetch is IO bound, not CPU bound.  This is a case where you're threading to wait on a background task, not threading to maximize CPU usage.  Don't worry about thead perf in such a scenario.

Comment: Im nor concerned - i just want to know the diffrence ! (in some case its extremely processor intensive algorithm)

Comment: @Niklas: Is it spawning multiple sub-tasks?  If so, then I might look into the task parallel library, especially `Parallel.ForEach`.  But the main task thread itself might still use a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @Niklas: "in some case its extremely processor intensive" doesn't match any of the scenarios in your original question.  You might want to clarify what type of CPU-bound activity you need threads for, and mention the type of analysis you've done on parallizability of the code.  See [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law).  Until you've done that analysis and maximized/switched your algorithm to maximize parallizaibility, the perf of the thread pool or thread spawning code will be a moot point.  For most scenarios it probably won't have as much impact as you think.

Comment: Well i understand now my question is to wide, i will ask it again when i have a more specifik example. Thank you !